# MySQL wrong result using MIN() function

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Question:

In this example, we have the grades of 5 students from school 1. We want to know which student had the lowest grade.

We were expecting to get student number 4, but SQL returns student 1

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `school_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `grade` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO `table1` (`school_id`, `student_id`, `grade`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 20),
    (1, 2, 15),
    (1, 3, 18),
    (1, 4, 12),
    (1, 5, 15);
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT t1.`school_id`, t1.`student_id`, MIN(t1.grade)
FROM table1 as t1
WHERE t1.`school_id`=1
GROUP BY t1.`school_id`;
```

Printscreen:

[image: Print Screen]

Comment: Plain text is almost always better than a screenshot. If you can just paste that in, it usually helps.

Comment: You're asking for the minimum grade for the school and then basically picking a random student ID since that's not part of the group operation. This would produce a warning in MySQL 5.7. What you need to do is have an intermediate query where you `ORDER BY grade` and take the first from each school.

Comment: Agree with @tadman ,  grouping will  group and eliminate some data,  so MIN() will return whatever value in the group.

Comment: See [groupwise max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY grade LIMIT 1
```

If you want the worst performing student in each school, then that's...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM table1 x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT school_id
            , MIN(grade) grade 
         FROM table1
        GROUP
           BY school_id
     ) y
    ON y.school_id = x.school_id
   AND y.grade = x.grade;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f44cb2/1

Answer (score 0):

With @tadman's tip, we came up with a solution:

You can find it bellow in case you came across with this same issue.

*We didn't understand why we have to use the **limit**. if we take out the **limit** line, we will get a wrong result*

```
SELECT t2.`school_id`, t2.`student_id`, t2.grade
FROM 
    (
    SELECT t1.`school_id`, t1.`student_id`, t1.grade
    FROM table1 as t1
    WHERE t1.`school_id`=1
    ORDER BY t1.`grade` ASC
    limit 4294967295
    )
as t2
GROUP BY t2.`school_id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some more requirements for your problem, I guess you would be good with just:

```
select t1.school_id, t1.student_id, t1.grade
from table1 as t1,
(select school_id, min(grade) as grade from table1 group by school_id) as t2
where t1.school_id=t2.school_id
and t1.grade=t2.grade;
```